# laravel-echo-server : The term 'laravel-echo-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: laravel, npm, error-handling, command, npm-package

laravel-echo-server : The term 'laravel-echo-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1

- laravel-echo-server init
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (laravel-echo-server:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

npm install -g laravel-echo-server
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 204 packages in 13s

17 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

Comment: Please provide more than simply the error messages and `npm` output you're receiving. I'm not sure if this is significant either, but it looks like you're using PowerShell, so it might be worth calling that out to help give others more context

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try with complete path of the command `node_modules/.bin/laravel-echo-server init`